# Expressão para tratar URL com parâmetro

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-replace

**NOTIFICAÇÃO**

As soluções abaixo, unicamente não terá grandes serventias, com elas é necessário anteriormente já ter implementado URL amigável, e também verificações de exibição do conteúdos do sistema que será implementado, aqui apenas vou dar exemplos de entradas de endereços completas recebidas na URL, para cada projeto em especifico o pórprio sistema já deve ter um tratamento de recebimento de parâmetro assim com o meu ou tentar se basear no que a função pode oferecer para implementá-la. Mas afinal qual o objetivo dela então?

Se o seu sistema já não está trazendo os dados caso seja solicitado uma URL do tipo "meu-site///an*i#maç!ao" e com isso trás algo como "página não encontrada..."

Ótimo! A função terá serventia e irá tentar redirecionar caso o próprio servidor já não bloqueie com erro 400

OBJETIVOS:

**1) Quando não se tem parâmetros de busca via GET do tipo "?"**

```
meu-site///an*i#maç!ao//##minha-postagem/
```

para isso!

```
meu-site/animação/minha-postagem
```

utilizo:

```
if(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-\/]/','',$url)){  
       //remove caracteres especiais permitindo hífen,e barra
      $nova_url= preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-\/]/','',$url);
}


if(preg_replace(('/(\/)\1+/',$url)){
      //remove varias barras seguidas
     $nova_url= preg_replace('/(\/)\1+/','$1', $url);
}
```

***** Solicitação de Melhoria: (poderia remover barra se houvesse na última posição) *****

**2) Quando eu tenho somente o parâmetro de busca via GET do tipo "?" sem paginação:**

```
meu-site/@#$%%@?sWXX=palavra
```

para isso!

```
meu-site/?s=palavra
```

Implementado (função criada e explicada abaixo)

```
 preg_match('/^.*?\?.*?s.*?=$/', $str)) {return "?s=";}
```

**3) Agora quando eu tenho paginação e parâmetro de busca juntos**

```
 meu-site/!anim a cao/!!!page/@#$%%@?sWXX=palavra
```

para isso!

```
meu-site/animacao/page/2?s=palavra
```

Implementado (função criada e explicada abaixo)

```
 if (preg_match('{^((?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*)+)/.*?p.*?a.*?g.*?e.*?/.*?(\d+).*?\?.*?s.*?=(.*)$}', $str, $matches)) {
        $trecho1 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $matches[1]);
        return "{$trecho1}/page/{$matches[2]}?s={$matches[3]}";
    }
```

Enfim, sei que existem muitas possibilidades de entradas de dados, mas como disse essas expressões servem para auxiliar uma URL digitada "erroneamente" a chegar no conteúdo pretendido, diga-se de passagem melhorando até uma possível duplicação de conteúdo! Isso era o que eu precisava mas se pode melhorar, aqueles que quiserem ajudar a modificar minhas próprias funções mesmo, comentem e ajudem a melhorar o código!

**ABAIXO VEM O PEDIDO E AS EXPLICAÇÕES**

Preciso de uma expressão regular em PHP que preserve meu parâmetro de busca. Meu parâmetro no site chama `s` (abreviação de *search*, assim como a maioria dos sites), logo quando eu for fazer uma busca no site via GET o navegador vai interpretar assim:

```
meu-site/?s=
```

Basicamente o que preciso é se houver qualquer coisa antes do parâmetro `?s=` ou qualquer coisa no meio dele, o `preg_replace` remova e me retorne a string da maneira limpa acima.

Vamos lá então, o que preciso que essa expressão faça:

Primeira expressão

1. Se não há parâmetro algum além do "?s=" na string não faça nada se ela estiver assim!

   ```
   ?s=
   ```

Caso contrário remova tudo o que está entre ela (após não precisa, o navegador entende como a palavra de busca), e tudo o que está antes! Permitindo apenas caracteres `a-z`, números `0-9`, 1 barra única (não seguida) e hífen, como as expressões que fiz abaixo ex:

Entrada:

a) `???!!?s=`

b) `///()!?s=`

c) `!?s!=`

Saída:

```
?s=
```

Segunda expressão

2. Agora se tiver mais parâmetros na URL além do `s` (não se preocupe já verifico isso tudo) apenas interprete a string de entrada.

OBS: para paginação, eu não utilizo mesmo a barra após o número da paginação...

```
animacao/page/2?s=
```

Entrada:

1) `animacao/!pa*ge)*&/2?s=`

2) `animacao////!?page))/2?s!=`

3) `animacao/!?pa_ge))/!@2?s*!=`

Saída:

```
animacao/page/2?s=
```

Essas minhas expressões que fiz funcionam bem em todo site, só que somente se não houver parâmetro de busca via GET como por exemplo "?s=", enfim já utilizo para tratar:

```
<?php 
//remove caracteres especiais,permitindo apenas / e hífen
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-\/]/','',$url);

//remove barras varias barras
preg_replace('/(\/)\1+/','$1', $url);

//remove várias interrogações seguidas
preg_replace('/([?])\1+/','$1', $url);
?>
```

---

Atualização do pedido em relação aos comentários

A função que o Usuário "hkotsubo" ofereceu está de acordo com o que preciso, lendo sua ótima explicação sobre a mesma, testei e identifiquei uma melhoria caso possível.

O valor que a expressão recebe na "$matches[1]", creio que nesse caso a palavra "animacao" (posso estar errado) não está funcionando casa tenha espaço antes, entre ou após a palavra.... e caracteres especiais...

O que preciso:

Se possível de permitir hífen, e se houver espaço ou caracteres especiais em qualquer posição remova.
O hífen creio que consegui adicionando nesse trecho "a-zA-Z-" agora o espaço precisa de de um tratamento...

Entrada:(espaço)

1) `ani mac ao /page/2?s=`

2) `a!!@*ni-ma-cao!/page/2?s=`

Saida:

```
animacao/page/2?s=
```

Comment: Dúvidas: `sQ!=` vira `s=` - por que o `Q` some? Não deveria ser `sQ=`? Ou só pode ter um parâmetro chamado `s`? E por que `![]}page!)///2?s=` vira `page/2?s=`, mas `!!@SSDwe?s=` vira `?s=`? Qual o critério para `page` não sumir e `SSDwe` sumir? Só pode ter o `s`, ou pode ter `?s=a&xyz=abc&etc=123....`? Enfim, não ficou claro para mim todos os critérios...

Comment: Também fiquei com a dúvida do @hkotsubo .... Acho que você poderia exemplificar melhor.. Tipo: Se a url for assim: `meu-site/!!@SSDwe?s=` quero que fique assim: `meu-site/?s=` por exemplo... Se ela for "assado" ... Quero que fique assim... e tal...

Comment: sim vou explicar direitinho...

Comment: Editada, qualquer coisa me pergunte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi exatamente todas as regras e talvez eu esteja simplificando demais o problema, mas vamos lá:

---

#### Parâmetro `s`

Para o parâmetro `s`, você quer que o resultado final seja a string `?s=`, e quer eliminar todos os demais caracteres que não façam parte desta string.

Então na verdade você não precisa fazer substituições mirabolantes, basta verificar se existe um `?` em algum lugar da string, em seguida, verifique se depois existe um `s`, e se no final existe um `=`:

```
function ajusta_parametro($str) {
    // se tiver algum "?", depois algum "s", e termina com "="
    if (preg_match('/^.*?\?.*?s.*?=$/', $str)) {
        return "?s=";
    }
    // se não estiver no formato correto, retorna '' ou dá erro, você decide
    ...
}
```

Usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` (início da string) e `$` (final da string), para garantir que a string toda tem o formato que quero. Depois usei `.*?` (zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere). Lembrando que o `.*` é [ganancioso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365714/112052) e sempre pega a maior quantidade possível de caracteres, mas colocando o `?` logo depois eu cancelo este comportamento, e a regex passa a verificar a menor sequência possível. (neste caso específico acho que não faz muita diferença, talvez seja ligeiramente mais rápido por não precisar pegar a maior sequência possível).

Depois tenho `\?` (o próprio caractere "ponto de interrogação"), seguido de zero ou mais caracteres, seguido de `s`, seguido de zero ou mais caracteres, seguido de `=` e o final da string. Ou seja, a regex verifica se tem algum `?` na string, e se depois há um `s` (podendo ou não ter qualquer coisa no meio), e se depois há um `=` (podendo ou não ter qualquer coisa antes dele).

Se a string tiver esse formato, simplesmente retorno `?s=`. Senão, você decide se vai retornar algo (string vazia talvez) ou se mostra uma mensagem de erro.

Com isso, todas as strings abaixo retornam `?s=`:

```
echo ajusta_parametro('???!!?s='), "\n";
echo ajusta_parametro('///()!?s='), "\n";
echo ajusta_parametro('!?s!='), "\n";
echo ajusta_parametro('!?sQ!='), "\n";
```

#### Paginação

Para a paginação, podemos usar um raciocínio parecido. Pelo que vi, do formato `animacao/page/2`, vou assumir que é:

- algum texto (sequência de letras)
- /page/número(s)

Para o texto, podemos usar `[a-zA-Z]+`. `page` sempre será fixo e eu uso algo similar ao que fiz para o parâmetro `s` (vejo se tem um `p`, seguido de qualquer coisa, seguido de `a`, etc). E para o número, eu uso `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos).

Outro detalhe é que em PHP geralmente os exemplos de regex usam `/regex/` (com as barras delimitando a expressão). Se eu quiser colocar uma barra dentro da expressão, tenho que escrever como `\/`. Mas eu também posso mudar os delimitadores para qualquer coisa, e com isso não preciso escapar a barra com `\`. A regex fica assim:

```
function ajusta_page($str) {
    // se tiver algum texto/page/número, podendo ter vários caracteres entre eles
    // usei { } para delimitar a regex (em vez de / /)
    if (preg_match('{^([a-zA-Z]+)/.*?p.*?a.*?g.*?e.*?/.*?(\d+).*?$}', $str, $matches)) {
        return "{$matches[1]}/page/{$matches[2]}";
    }
    // se não estiver no formato correto, retorna '' ou dá erro, você decide
}
```

Nesse caso, coloquei `[a-zA-Z]+` e `\d+` entre parênteses, pois isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que são colocados na variável `$matches`. Assim, `$matches[1]` corresponde ao primeiro parênteses (no caso, `[a-zA-Z]+`, o nome da página), e o `$matches[2]` corresponde ao segundo parênteses (`\d+`, o número da página). Eu junto tudo e o resultado será "nome/page/número".

Todos os casos abaixo imprimem `animacao/page/2`:

```
echo ajusta_page("animacao/!page)&/2"), "\n";
echo ajusta_page("animacao////!?page))/2"), "\n";
echo ajusta_page("animacao/!?pa_ge))/!@2"), "\n";
```

---

#### Agora é só juntar tudo

Juntando as duas regex em uma só, temos:

```
function ajusta($str) {
    if (preg_match('{^([a-zA-Z]+)/.*?p.*?a.*?g.*?e.*?/.*?(\d+).*?\?.*?s.*?=$}', $str, $matches)) {
        return "{$matches[1]}/page/{$matches[2]}?s=";
    }
    // se não estiver no formato correto, retorna '' ou dá erro, você decide
}
```

Todos os casos abaixo resultam em `animacao/page/2?s=`:

```
echo ajusta("animacao/!page)&/2???!!?s="), "\n";
echo ajusta("animacao////!?page))/2///()!?s="), "\n";
echo ajusta("animacao/!?pa_ge))/!@2!?s!="), "\n";
echo ajusta("animacao/!?pa_ge))/!@2!?sQ!="), "\n";
```

---

Se quiser que tenha mais coisas depois do `=` (e tanto faz o que são essas coisas), basta adicionar `.*` depois dele. Mas se quiser juntar essas coisas na string, use outro grupo de captura:

```
function ajusta($str) {
    // se tiver algum texto/page/número, podendo ter vários caracteres entre eles
    if (preg_match('{^([a-zA-Z]+)/.*?p.*?a.*?g.*?e.*?/.*?(\d+).*?\?.*?s.*?=(.*)$}', $str, $matches)) {
        return "{$matches[1]}/page/{$matches[2]}?s={$matches[3]}";
    }
    // se não estiver no formato correto, retorna '' ou dá erro, você decide
}
```

Assim, strings como `animacao/!?pa_ge))/!@2!?sQ!=valor&param=outrovalor` se transforma em `animacao/page/2?s=valor&param=outrovalor`.

---

#### Trecho inicial com caracteres especiais

No [caso adicionado posteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/365250/revisions#spacer-5e308662-2518-41ae-b640-e59e84b4d5a8) na pergunta, a primeira parte ("animacao") também pode ter vários caracteres não-alfanuméricos entre as letras. Se o texto final for sempre "animacao", bastaria usar uma abordagem similar ao que foi feito com "page": colocar a letra `a`, seguido de `.*?`, seguido de `n`, seguido de `.*?`, e assim por diante.

Mas se puder ter qualquer texto, podemos usar `((?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*)+)`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- `(?:` cria um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Isso faz com que os parênteses não adicionem um novo valor em `$matches` - se eu só usasse `(` (sem o `?:`), isso mudaria os índices dos demais parênteses da expressão (`$matches[2]`, `$matches[3]`, etc - cada par de parênteses a mais adiciona um novo índice em `$matches`, e se eu não quiser isso, basta usar `(?:`).
- `[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*` é "uma letra seguida de zero ou mais caracteres que não são letras". Tudo isso está dentro do grupo de não-captura e seguido de um `+`, ou seja, eu posso ter várias vezes essa sequência de "letra seguida de não-letras"
- tudo isso está dentro de parênteses, para formar um grupo de captura (no caso, será `$matches1`).

O restante da expressão (para tratar "pages/X/?s=") é igual. O único detalhe é que `$matches[1]` terá a primeira parte da URL juntamente com os caracteres "não-letras", então eu preciso de um `preg_replace` adicional antes de construir a string final:

```
function ajusta($str) {
    // se tiver algum texto/page/número, podendo ter vários caracteres entre eles
    if (preg_match('{^((?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*)+)/.*?p.*?a.*?g.*?e.*?/.*?(\d+).*?\?.*?s.*?=(.*)$}', $str, $matches)) {
        $trecho1 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $matches[1]);
        return "{$trecho1}/page/{$matches[2]}?s={$matches[3]}";
    }
    // se não estiver no formato correto, retorna '' ou dá erro, você decide
}
```

Com isso, os casos abaixo imprimem `animacao/page/2?s=`:

```
echo ajusta("ani mac ao /!?pa_ge))/!@2!?s!="), "\n";
echo ajusta("a!!@*ni-ma-cao!/!?pa_ge))/!@2!?s!="), "\n";
```

---

#### Considerações finais

Embora tenha sido possível resolver com regex, não sei se é de fato a melhor abordagem.

Seu programa está aceitando "qualquer coisa" e tentando extrair uma string válida dali. O problema é que há possibilidades demais a serem consideradas, e quanto mais casos você adiciona, mais complexa - e lenta - a regex vai ficando.

Se "aceitar qualquer coisa e tentar extrair uma string válida" é um requisito primordial do sistema, então não tem jeito, você terá que conviver com esta regex (e dar manutenção a cada vez que surgir um caso novo mais complicado de tratar).

Mas se puder, talvez seja melhor ter um meio-termo: uma regex que consegue validar os casos mais comuns e/ou básicos, mas que simplesmente falha se for algo complicado demais, e aí o sistema mostra uma mensagem de erro e informa quais os formatos aceitos, por exemplo - é só uma sugestão, pois não sei como será a sua interface com o usuário nem os seus requisitos (só me parece complicado demais tentar prever todas as possibilidades, mas claro que tudo depende dos seus casos de uso).

Enfim, regex é uma ferramenta poderosa, útil e - na minha opinião - muito legal de se usar, mas [nem sempre é a melhor](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) - nem a única - solução para tudo.

Comment: Meu na boa I-M-P-O-S-S-Í-V-E-L DE MAS PARA MIM!

Comment: PERFEITO! exatamente o que queria, mas não sabia nem por onde começar!

Comment: Testando aqui te pergunto... na "$matche[1]" ele não está retornando caso tenha número ou nem hífen ou espaço entre as palavras, o espaço pode remover...Tanto no início, entre, ou no final do parâmetro, o restante está funcionando normalmente! Teria como modificar man?

Comment: @CaioLourençon Sugiro que edite a pergunta  e coloque os detalhes desse caso que falhou, pois não entendi exatamente o que aconteceu. Mas infelizmente só vou conseguir ver isso depois do feriado :-)

Comment: @CaioLourençon Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Meu, na boa.. Sabe muito! Está funcionando perfeitamente, e como você explicou passo a passo posso tentar fazer alguma modificação s eu precisar e buscar mais informações posteriormente! Mas sim, você conseguiu exatamente o que eu achei que era inviável em uma única regex, sei que as possibilidades são muitas mais que estás, mas é bem complexo para que entende o mínimo com eu!

Comment: Li a suas "Considerações finais" essa Regex que tu bolou não vai ser utilizada de maneira nenhuma para prevenir qualquer tido de ataque no quesito segurança do sistema, pelo contrário ela vai somente auxiliar no funcionamento das requisições pelos usuários... tem alguma forma deu explicar no chat para você?

Comment: @CaioLourençon Tenho alguns minutos se quiser..

Comment: @CaioLourençon Tenta aí: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90639/expressao-para-tratar-url-com-parametro

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no que você colocou como exemplos, criei esse código comentado:

```
$url = "animacao/!?page))/!@2?s*!=";

// pega todas as palavras que contenham caracteres de az, AZ, 0-9, incluindo o caractere _ (sublinhado).
// OU pega a parte que tem ( ?s )
preg_match_all('/(\w|\?s)+/', $url, $partes);

// nova url que será usada
$novaUrl = "";

foreach($partes[0] as $parte){
    if(strpos($parte, "?s")){
        // se a parte a ser analisada for ( ?s ) insira na $novaUrl com um ( = ) no final
        $novaUrl .= $parte."=";
        continue; // continue o loop
    }
    // qualquer outra parte insere com uma barra no final
    $novaUrl .= $parte."/";
}

// se o último caracter for uma barra ( / ) retire ela da string
if(substr($novaUrl,  -1) == "/")
$novaUrl = substr($novaUrl, 0, -1);

// mostra o resultado
echo $novaUrl;
```

**[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/rbvLvy)**

Comment: Andrei Coelho, Testei agora sua função, com comandos básico ela oferece um suporte bom, mas tente jogar essa string que testei na função: "an'i-ma-c'a  o/pa|ge/!@2?ssssssssssss*!="

Comment: De qualquer maneira estou tirando exemplos dela para fazer outras mais simples!

Comment: @CaioLourençon vou fazer uma outra resposta mais precisa depois