# Regex - Selecionando a primeira ocorrência de uma sequência de um bloco de números

Tags: java, regex

Tenho uma `String` mais ou menos assim:

```
987654 original4343 - Co 123456 asd.pdf
```

Esta `String` pode variar os agrupamentos de números, mas o que eu preciso é pegar o agrupamento que tenha 6 dígitos.

Então eu fiz essa regex:

```
.*([0-9]{6}).*
```

O problema é que está me retornando a última ocorrência, mas eu preciso da primeira. No exemplo que eu citei acima, está retornando:`123456`

Mas eu preciso que retorne: `987654`

Eu tentei usar o `\b` ou outras alternativas que procurei, mas em nenhuma eu fui feliz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua regex pegou a última ocorrência dos 6 dígitos porque o quantificador `*` é [ganancioso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy): ele pega a **maior sequência possível** de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão.

E como você usou `.*` e o ponto significa "qualquer caractere" (qualquer um, **inclusive números**¹), acontece o seguinte:

- `.*` pega o trecho `987654 original4343 - Co` (é uma sequência de zero ou mais caracteres)
- `[0-9]{6}` pega o trecho `123456` (uma sequência de 6 dígitos)

A regex até poderia ter pego o `987654`, mas como `.*` é ganancioso, ele tenta pegar a maior sequência de caracteres que puder. E como o ponto pode ser qualquer caractere, inclusive números, o `987654` acaba sendo "engolido" pelo `.*` (já que depois a regex encontrou outra sequência de 6 dígitos que satisfaz a sua "ganância").

---

Neste caso, você não precisa do `.*`, pode usar apenas a sequência de 6 dígitos, já que o `Matcher` por padrão começa a busca no início da `String`, e vai avançando até encontrar algo:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String s = "987654 original4343 - Co 123456 asd.pdf";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{6}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) { // verifica se encontrou
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

É importante verificar se o [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) retorna `true`. Se a `String` não tiver nenhuma sequência de 6 dígitos (se `find()` retornar `false`) e você chamar [`group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--) logo em seguida, o resultado será um `java.lang.IllegalStateException` ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/PTXqqu)).

O código acima imprime `987654`. Como a regex não tem mais `.*`, ela não precisa pegar a maior sequência de caracteres possível. Usando somente `[0-9]{6}`, ela se concentra em verificar apenas 6 dígitos seguidos.

---

#### Atenção

Mas ainda tem um detalhe. Se tivermos a `String`:

```
1234567 abc 987654
```

Ela começa com um número de 7 dígitos, mas se usarmos o código acima, o resultado será `123456` (já que são 6 dígitos seguidos - a sua regex não disse se podia ou não ter outro dígito depois). Se é isso que você precisa, pode usar o código acima. Mas se quiser pegar apenas as sequências de 6 dígitos que não tenham nenhum outro dígito antes ou depois, o código muda um pouco:

```
String s = "1234567 abc 987654";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{6}(?=[^0-9]|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Isso imprime `987654`. Acrescentei algumas coisas na expressão para garantir que ela pegue somente 6 dígitos que não tenham nenhum outro dígito antes ou depois. Vamos por partes:

O [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` significa "início da string". O caractere `|` [significa "ou"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) e `[^0-9]` é "qualquer coisa [que **não** seja](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) um dígito de 0 a 9". Ou seja, `^|[^0-9]` significa "o início da string **ou** um caractere que não é dígito".

Eu coloquei tudo dentro de um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (indicado por `(?<=`). Ele serve para verificar se algo existe antes da posição atual. No caso, pode ser o início da string ou algum caractere que não seja dígito.

Em seguida coloquei `[0-9]{6}`, que é o que eu quero pegar de fato.

Por fim temos um *lookahead* (indicado por `(?=`), que é similar ao *lookbehind*: ele serve para verificar se algo existe depois da posição atual. E dentro dele temos: `[^0-9]|$` - um caractere que não é um dígito **ou** o final da string (`$`),

Ou seja, a regex vai pegar as sequências de 6 dígitos, desde que não tenham nenhum outro dígito antes ou depois. O código acima imprime `987654`.

---

Você disse que tentou usar `\b`, mas ele significa uma "fronteira entre palavras" ([*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)), ou seja, posições da string que tem um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois (ou vice-versa). Então se tiver casos como `a123456`, ele não é considerado, pois existe uma letra antes dos dígitos, e a letra não é considerada uma "fronteira entre palavras". Ex:

```
String s = "1234567 abc a987654 111222";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9]{6}\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Este código imprime `111222`. O `a987654` não foi pego porque tem um `a` antes dos dígitos (portanto, a posição antes do `9` não corresponde a `\b`).

Usando `(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{6}(?=[^0-9]|$)`, como já vimos, o código retorna `987654`. Então escolha a regex que melhor se adequar aos seus dados e ao que você precisa extrair deles.

---

### Mais alguns detalhes

Outra alternativa é usar os [atalhos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` (que corresponde a `[0-9]`) e `\D` (que corresponde a `[^0-9]`). Lembrando que dentro de strings o caractere `\` deve ser escapado e escrito como `\\`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\D)\\d{6}(?=\\D|$)");
```

E se quiser obter todas as ocorrências (e não só a primeira), basta fazer um *loop*:

```
while (m.find()) { // enquanto tiver sequências de 6 dígitos, imprime
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

E caso vá processar várias strings diferentes, não precisa criar o `Pattern` e `Matcher` toda hora. Basta criar uma vez e ir *resetando* o `Matcher` a cada iteração:

```
String[] strings = {
    "987654 original4343 - Co 123456 asd.pdf",
    "1234567 abc 987654",
    "1234567 abc a987654 111222" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\D)\\d{6}(?=\\D|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");
for (String s : strings) {
    m.reset(s); // resetar o Matcher com outra string
    System.out.println("Testando " + s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("- encontrado: " + m.group());
    }
}
```

A saída é:

```
Testando 987654 original4343 - Co 123456 asd.pdf
- encontrado: 987654
- encontrado: 123456
Testando 1234567 abc 987654
- encontrado: 987654
Testando 1234567 abc a987654 111222
- encontrado: 987654
- encontrado: 111222
```

---

(1): Na verdade o ponto, por padrão, corresponde a qualquer caractere exceto [quebras de linha](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt). Mas é possível fazer com que ele também considere quebras de linha, usando a *flag* [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

Answer (score 2):

Essa REGEX `.*([0-9]{6}).*` além de trazer o último número dentro do grupo, pois como foi detalhado na resposta do @hkotsubo, o seu contador (.*) traz o máximo possível de qualquer caractere que esteja antes do número de 6 dígitos e depois dele, trazendo toda a String consigo.

A forma mais simples que eu vejo para trazer os números é isso:

```
  ([0-9]{6}) // Trazer um grupo de números com 6 dígitos
```

Dependendo do que realmente precisa, pode se fazer necessário analisar cada parte encontrada pela regex, ou dar mais complexidade a ela para fazer um filtro mais específico.

Se você precisa apenas da primeira ocorrência, basta fazer isso:

```
   String str = "987654 original4343 - Co 123456 asd.pdf";

   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{6})");    
   Matcher pesquisa = regex.matcher(str);    
   pesquisa.find();
   System.out.println(pesquisa.group());// primeira ocorrência
```

Mas você quiser todos os números encontrados, poderá fazer assim:

```
   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{6})");    
   Matcher pesquisa = regex.matcher(str);    
   while (pesquisa.find()) {    
        System.out.println(pesquisa.group());
   }
```

Só não esquece de importar as classes:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

Interessante destacar esta citação do @hkotsubo:

> Esse `.*` é traiçoeiro, alguns autores mais radicais dizem para "nunca"
>   usar - que acho meio exagerado, claro, vc deve usar com cuidado, mas
>   se [souber o que está fazendo](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) não tem problema nenhum

Comment: "Eu não sei como essa REGEX .*([0-9]{6}).* trouxe apenas o último número" - Trouxe apenas o ultimo porque o primeiro `.*` é *greedy* logo apanha o máximo que puder.

Comment: De fato, sobre o `.*`, é o que o @Isac falou. Coloquei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365714/112052) com uma explicação detalhando um pouco isso - e mais algumas observações :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo sim... Acabei me expressando mal.

Comment: @Isac tinha me expressado mal... O que eu quis dizer "Eu não sei como essa REGEX[..]" é que ela não pega APENAS o último número. E sim TODA a String. Eu fiz testes com java e do jeito que estava aquela regex, puxava tudo!

Comment: De qualquer forma, editei a resposta para ficar mais claro. =)

Comment: Ele traz toda a string por causa do **segundo** `.*` depois dos dígitos. A "ganância" vale para ambos: o primeiro `.*` pega o máximo possível antes dos dígitos (fazendo com que considere a última sequência de 6 dígitos), e o segundo pega todo o resto depois desses 6 dígitos (ou seja, vai até o final da string). O resultado é a string inteira... Esse `.*` é traiçoeiro, alguns autores mais radicais dizem para "nunca" usar - que acho meio exagerado, claro, vc deve usar com cuidado, mas [se souber o que está fazendo](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) não tem problema nenhum.

Comment: @hkotsubo sim... Vou inserir isso que você disse.