# Expressão regular para caracteres repetidos

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Alguém sabe se é possível verificar se um string possui todos caracteres iguais? Por exemplo, pode caracteres seguidos ou mais de um na mesma string, mas não todos iguais:

Isso pode:

```
$str = "ttste";
```

Mas não isso:

```
$str ="ttttttt";
```

Comment: Olá acabei de verificar a expressão acima, mas não é o que procuro, esta somente reconhece se existem caracteres iguais seguidos, e quero que reconheça somente se TODOS forem iguais, caso 1 ja não seja me retorne FALSE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [resposta do Andrei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365811/112052) é bem mais simples, mas já que foi pedida uma solução com expressões regulares, segue abaixo:

```
if (preg_match('/^(.)\1*$/', $str)) {
    // string tem todos os caracteres iguais
}
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Isso garante que ela só terá o que estiver especificado na expressão.

Em seguida temos `(.)`: o ponto significa "[qualquer caractere (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)", e os parênteses formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Isso quer dizer que o primeiro caractere da string (pois está logo depois do `^`) será capturado por este grupo.

Em seguida temos `\1`, que é uma [*backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), ou seja, ela significa "o mesmo texto que foi capturado no primeiro grupo". No caso, o primeiro grupo é `(.)` (que é o primeiro caractere da string, pois ele aparece logo depois do `^`).

Em seguida temos o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Portanto, `\1*` quer dizer que o `\1` (o mesmo caractere que está no início da string) pode se repetir várias vezes.

Resumindo, `^` faz a regex verificar desde o início da string, `(.)` pega o primeiro caractere e captura (possibilitando o uso de `\1`). Em seguida, `\1*` verifica se esse mesmo caractere se repete várias vezes, até o final da string (`$`).

Isso garante que a string terá o mesmo caractere do início ao fim. Se tiver algum caractere diferente, a regex falha.

---

Só um detalhe: eu usei `*`, que significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências", o que quer dizer que se a string tiver somente um caractere, a regex considera que ela é válida. Mas se quiser que a string tenha no mínimo dois caracteres, pode trocar para:

```
preg_match('/^(.)\1+$/', $str)
```

O `+` significa "**uma** ou mais ocorrências". Então o ponto pega o primeiro caractere, e o `\1+` garante que haverá pelo menos mais um caractere na regex.

---

Outro detalhe é que `.` pega qualquer caractere **mesmo**. Então se a string for `-------` ou `~~~`, a regex também considera válida.

Você pode limitar para letras trocando o ponto por `[a-zA-Z]`, por exemplo, que só vai aceitar letras de `a` a `z` (maiúsculas ou minúsculas). Ou ainda usar `\w` junto com a flag `u` para aceitar caracteres acentuados (repare no `u` logo após a segunda barra):

```
preg_match('/^(\w)\1*$/u', "ççç"); // válido
preg_match('/^(\w)\1*$/', "ççç"); // inválido
```

Aliás, a flag `u` também dá essa diferença se usarmos o ponto:

```
preg_match('/^(.)\1*$/u', "áá"); // true
preg_match('/^(.)\1*$/', "áá"); // false
```

Enfim, veja na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pcre.pattern.php) todas as possibilidades.

---

#### Usando as funções *multibyte*

Outra opção - sem usar regex - é [habilitar](http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-mbstring-in-php-46.html) as [funções *multibyte*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.mbstring.php), que funcionam tanto para strings "normais" (ASCII), como `tttt`, quanto para as multi-bytes, que possuem caracteres acentuados, etc:

```
function todos_caracteres_iguais($str) {
    $first = mb_substr($str, 0, 1);
    $len = mb_strlen($str);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
        if ($char != $first) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Sendo assim, esta função funcionará para todas as strings abaixo:

```
todos_caracteres_iguais("ááá") // true
todos_caracteres_iguais("ááç")) // false
todos_caracteres_iguais("ttttttt") // true
todos_caracteres_iguais("tttste")) // false
```

Se você usar um `for` sem as funções *multi-byte*:

```
$first = $str[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $char = $str[$i];
    if ($char != $first) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Ele até funciona para `tttt` e `ttste`, mas falha para `ááá`.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Você gosta de um regex hein! =)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Haha! É que a pergunta pediu uma solução com regex... Embora eu ache que não é a solução mais simples :-)

Comment: XD ... Sim! Eu também gosto de brincar com regex!

Comment: Sensacional meu jovem! Além de tudo ainda explica.

Comment: Se gosta de regex quer encarar (; ? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365250/expess%c3%a3o-para-tratar-url-com-par%c3%a2metro

Comment: @CaioLourençon Eu tinha visto essa pergunta, mas na hora estava sem tempo e acabei esquecendo e deixando de lado. Vou voltar para ela assim que puder :-)

Comment: Achei que teria visto mesmo, pois tem muitas visualizações... agradeço então se poder disponibilizar um tempo para esta causa, é a ultima coisa para eu terminar meu projeto! Cara na boa nunca mais faço um projeto do zero ( sem auxilio de frameworks e CMS já prontos ), é muita detalhe para cuidar.

Comment: Regex eu só uso uma vez por ano, e nunca consigo guardar... mas essa explicação ampliou mais meus conhecimentos! Muito obrigado pela ótima explicação!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `count_chars` para contar os caracteres e depois verificar se há mais de 1 elemento e se este elemento tem mais de 1 caractere.

```
$str = "tttttt";

$chars = count_chars($str, 1);
unset($chars[195]); // corrige a numeração com caracteres especiais 

if(count($chars) > 1 || reset($chars) == 1){
    echo "Esta string NÃO TEM todos os caracteres repetidos";
} else {
    echo "Esta string TEM todos os caracteres repetidos";
}
```

Esta linha retornará isso:

```
$chars = count_chars($str, 1);
// Array ( [116] => 6 )
```

Então, se houver apenas 1 elemento no array, significa que todos os caracteres são repetidos desde que haja mais de 1 caractere neste elemento. Mas se houver apenas 1 elemento no array e esse elemento tiver apenas 1 caractere, significa que essa string não tem todos os caracteres repetidos.

*obs.: Sei que você pediu uma expressão regular, mas eu acredito que usando a função do php para isso é mais fácil.*

Comment: Sim, havia conseguido de outra maneira também, mas de sua forma também chegamos no mesmo resultado.

Comment: @CaioLourençon sim... Tem várias formas de fazer isso! =)

Comment: @CaioLourençon uma solução com o `for` não é ruim!

Comment: Só cuidado que a solução não funciona para caracteres multi-bytes, por exemplo, `"ãããããã"`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem rasão. Fiz uma edição. Agora funciona com caracteres especiais de qualquer tipo.